# Stock WooCommerce mechanism that formats prices in product edit page

Tags: php, woocommerce

My e-shop is configured to use `,` for the decimal separator. So I have a task to show a postmeta representing a special price in the product edit page just below the regular and sale price input boxes. For that purpose I'll be using `woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data` filter to show my input box. The price is stored in a PHP float format in the DB, that is with `.` as the decimal separator.

My question is this: What is the stock mechanism that takes `_regular_price` that is stored with `.` as its decimal separator and converts it to using a `,`? I searched extensively WooCommerce source files and found out that the responsible piece of code for the regular price input box is this:

```
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'        => '_regular_price',
            'value'     => $product_object->get_regular_price( 'edit' ),
            'label'     => __( 'Regular price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
            'data_type' => 'price',
        )
    );
```

So I suppose that the whole game is played within the `get_regular_price()` method, which is only a shell for `$this->get_prop( 'regular_price', $context );`

So what is the exact stock piece of code that converts a price stored in the DB like `53.85` to `53,85` ?